# Cant Load JS And Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui, tailwind-in-js

I downloaded argon-dashboard *the free version*
to the best of my knowledge, I incorporated it to the system I made.

Now it cannot load the JS and stylesheet to a specific page.

the link is like this
`http://gsdwarehouse.test/inventory/inventory/0`

the error returns `404` which is I don't know why since I am not proficient in JavaScript.
[image: error image]

I have this code in my .js file

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".")[0];
var aux = window.location.pathname.split("/");
var to_build = '../';
// var to_build = (aux.includes('pages') || aux.includes('docs') ?'../':'./');
var root = window.location.pathname.split("/")

if (!aux.includes("pages")) {
  page = "dashboard";
}
loadStylesheet(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/css/perfect-scrollbar.css");
loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/perfect-scrollbar.js", true);
// loadStylesheet(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/css/perfect-scrollbar.css");
// loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/perfect-scrollbar.js", true);

if (document.querySelector("[slider]")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/carousel.js", true);
}

if (document.querySelector("nav [navbar-trigger]")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/navbar-collapse.js", true);
}

if (document.querySelector("[data-target='tooltip']")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/tooltips.js", true);
  loadStylesheet(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/css/tooltips.css");
}

if (document.querySelector("[nav-pills]")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/nav-pills.js", true);
}

if (document.querySelector("[dropdown-trigger]")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/dropdown.js", true);

}

if (document.querySelector("[fixed-plugin]")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/fixed-plugin.js", true);
}

if (document.querySelector("[navbar-main]") || document.querySelector("[navbar-profile]")) {
  if(document.querySelector("[navbar-main]")){
    loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/navbar-sticky.js", true);
  }
  if (document.querySelector("aside")) {
    loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/sidenav-burger.js", true);
  }
}

if (document.querySelector("canvas")) {
  loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/charts.js", true);
}

if (document.querySelector(".github-button")) {
  loadJS("https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js", true);
}

function loadJS(FILE_URL, async) {
  let dynamicScript = document.createElement("script");

  dynamicScript.setAttribute("src", FILE_URL);
  dynamicScript.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
  dynamicScript.setAttribute("async", async);

  document.head.appendChild(dynamicScript);
}

function loadStylesheet(FILE_URL) {
  let dynamicStylesheet = document.createElement("link");

  dynamicStylesheet.setAttribute("href", FILE_URL);
  dynamicStylesheet.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
  dynamicStylesheet.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");

  document.head.appendChild(dynamicStylesheet);
}
```

and also, i have this code in the min.js

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").pop().split(".")[0],
aux = window.location.pathname.split("/"),
to_build = "../" ,
// to_build = aux.includes("pages") || aux.includes("docs") ? "../" : "./",
root = window.location.pathname.split("/");
function loadJS(b, c) {
    let a = document.createElement("script");
    a.setAttribute("src", b),
    a.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"),
    a.setAttribute("async", c),
    document.head.appendChild(a)
}
function loadStylesheet(b) {
    let a = document.createElement("link");
    a.setAttribute("href", b),
    a.setAttribute("type", "text/css"),
    a.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet"),
    document.head.appendChild(a)
}
aux.includes("pages") || (page = "dashboard"),
loadStylesheet(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/css/perfect-scrollbar.css"),
loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/perfect-scrollbar.js", !0),
document.querySelector("[slider]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/carousel.js", !0),
document.querySelector("nav [navbar-trigger]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/navbar-collapse.js", !0),
document.querySelector("[data-target='tooltip']") && (loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/tooltips.js", !0),
loadStylesheet(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/css/tooltips.css")),
document.querySelector("[nav-pills]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/nav-pills.js", !0),
document.querySelector("[dropdown-trigger]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/dropdown.js", !0),
document.querySelector("[fixed-plugin]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/fixed-plugin.js", !0),
(document.querySelector("[navbar-main]") || document.querySelector("[navbar-profile]")) && (document.querySelector("[navbar-main]") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/navbar-sticky.js", !0),
document.querySelector("aside") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/sidenav-burger.js", !0)),
document.querySelector("canvas") && loadJS(to_build + "argon-dashboard-build/js/charts.js", !0),
document.querySelector(".github-button") && loadJS("https://buttons.github.io/buttons.js", !0)
```

I did try to filter the `inventory` in the path, like this in the .js

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory").pop().split(".")[0];
var aux = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory");
var to_build = '../';
// var to_build = (aux.includes('pages') || aux.includes('docs') ?'../':'./');
var root = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory")
```

and this in the min.js

```
var page = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory").pop().split(".")[0],
aux = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory"),
to_build = "../" ,
// to_build = aux.includes("pages") || aux.includes("docs") ? "../" : "./",
root = window.location.pathname.split("/").filter(segment => segment !== "inventory");
```

but, no luck.

> the code used above is from Product Page: https://www.creative-tim.com/product/argon-dashboard-tailwind Copyright 2022 Creative Tim (https://www.creative-tim.com)

Coded by [www.creative-tim.com](http://www.creative-tim.com)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the directly answer to your question, but I just solved a similar issue in my project running locally with CSS files and JS from argon-dashboard.

In the app.blade.php file, I changed the relative path (./assets/css/nucleo-svg.css) to an absolute path (/assets/css/nucleo-svg.css) and it allowed the assets to be referenced properly regardless of the current URL or route.

Be aware of your URLs in resources files